# To center 2 div inside a div wrapper without centering all my text

Tags: html, css

Other than using display: inline-block and text-align:center, do we have anyway to make 2 div center inside a div wrapper? I don't want my text to be center.

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-align: center;` on the wrapper div and `text-align:left;` on the child divs.

you can also use the `margin: 0 auto;` on the child divs instead of using text-aligns. But they will each have to have a width (px or %) and each div will be in its own row.

Comment: Do I need to use inline-block and if yes which method I should put in?

Comment: If you want the DIVs to appear on the same row, yes you need to set `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS margin is best way of centering a DIV. Add another DIV to hold the two centered ones with:

```
 margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a 2nd wrapper for the two divs, with a specified width and set it's margin auto.